# Getting FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION:field integrity exception: TotalPrice (total price must be specified):TotalPrice

Tags: apex, exception, field-update, opportunity-lineitem

I'm getting following exception while updating a custom field on Opportunity Product.
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION:field integrity exception: TotalPrice (total price must be specified):TotalPrice

Details:
custom_field__c is a checkbox field.
From the UI when custom_field__c value is made to true this field integrity exception is thrown.
But when i try to update custom_field__c from developer console it is saved without any exception.

TotalPrice, UnitPrice, SalesPrice and Quantity values are already present on the record.

I would like to do mass update for custom_field__c on Opportunity Products.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with doing the mass update via developer console?

Comment: @identigral, That I have to do manually for each record through dev console.

Comment: You can mass update them via a loop + SOQL, like this Account example in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm)

Comment: @identigral, Every Record has different value for custom_field__c. I would have to do update through workbench by uploading excel file.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this issue, kindly make sure the below for OpportunityLineItem(Opportunity Product) records:

1. We cannot set both TotalPrice and UnitPrice to null in the same Insert, update and Upsert call.
2. UnitPrice field or TotalPrice is required. You cannot specify both.
3. If you specify Discount and Quantity, UnitPrice field or TotalPrice is required.
4. TotalPrice field cannot be null if UnitPrice field is null.

Comment: I have added UnitPrice and totalPrice is calculated on insert of the record.

Comment: I'm performing an update on Opportunity Product so UnitPrice and TotalPrice are not null.

Comment: from where you are trying to update? From record page or data loader? also is there any flow or trigger on opportunity product? if yes, then deactivate and try to update

Comment: I tried from record page and workbench but got exception. I have deactivated flows, validation rules and trigger but still getting same issue.